# Angular full encapsulation when creating a hosted angular widget

Tags: angular

I have an angular widget that should be embedded in different sites and I have no knowledge about the sites that will embed it.

I cannot place the widget in an IFrame.

This means that the widget should be 100% encapsulated.

The widget is using components from certain libraries like:

angular bootstrap - https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

@angular/material

Some of the components from those libraries are using view encapsulation set to none which means one problem will be that my head will contain stuff like:

```
.mat-checkbox {...}
```

which is not good cause it might interfere with the host site styles.

Another problem is that I cannot afford class names like **.mat-checkbox**
cause this means that the host site can load a material design template and change my widget appearance.

I examined other companies solution like **hotjar**

they do not place in iframe and they simply hash their classnames (probably using a library for css in js like typestyle or postcss) which is a great solution for me - but

**how do i hash the classnames of the components from 3rd party libraries like material design and angular bootstrap?**

Things I tried:

- Angular elements for creating a web component
- Typestyle

Answer (score 2):

One thing you could try, which is not that Angulary is to use [TreeWalker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker) to go over all of the nodes in your widget in `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook and alter classes using `Renderer2` in a way you like. TreeWalker is supported by domino so it should even work with Angular Universal.

Comment: TreeWalker or MutationObserver are fine solutions for knowing that a change happen, and yes I can then use Renderer2. This solution will work for changing the class names.
Performance wise it will be better to just reflect the private platform browser service: DefaultDomRenderer2 which also works for me with much better performance. 
The problem I have now is that i need to change also the styles to match those class name so I need to somehow alter the angular material styles and hash those classnames and match them with the class names im changing in the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

You have written you have tried angular elements but didn't mention if you face any problem with it. I am creating a project which lives in other's project and analyze their project at run time. For me, the angular element was a perfect fit. If you use `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom` in your root component, your styles will automatically be scoped. You can use them in non angular project as well.

Comment: I tried ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom with angular elements.
the problem is when embedding a 3rd party component with ViewEncapsulation.None for example @angular/material BottomSheet.
Components like that, even though they are nested in my element with ShadowDom will still write their styles to the head section of the host styles.
Try to embed BottomSheet in your widget and examine the head section you will see those styles.